# Hibernate SQL ORA-01858 error when using # in the select clause field name

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

We use hibernate in our application which had SQL queries to fetch record count and data.

we used query similar to below (in which some of the select clause field name had '#' in it) like,

```
select count(*) as count 
from (
   select distinct field#1, field#2 
   from some_table1 st1, 
        some_table2 
   where st1.id = st2.id 
   and st1.updated_date between to_date(?, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:mi:ss) and to_date(?, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:mi:ss)
)
```

The query was in a properties file and using string paramterized methods to substitue bind variables.

using the log4j2 parameters to print the log information to console.

> ```
>   <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="debug"/>
>    <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug"/>
>   <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="trace"/>
> ```

i was able to print the bind values that are set to the query and didn't see any problem in it.

Within the application when i changed the query using eclipse editor got the below exception.

> WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1858, SQLState: 22008
>   ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

The log had the SQL query printed and it was working without any issue in Toad for oracle.

For some reason i noticed that the source of the file (not sure of what encoding it had) was working without any issue,
Even i used Beyond Compare tool to merge this to my working directory and the application works fine.

I am not sure whether the eclipse encoding could cause issue when # being used in the field names of select query.

Is this because of the encoding issue?

--
Confirmed that this is NOT an issue because of the encoding.

Comment: The problem isn't the `#` but the `(?, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:mi:ss)`. I assume that should really be `to_date(?, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:mi:ss)`

Comment: we used to form the query dynamically in the application, the bind variable set for the date was not correct, it had '%' in the date string. Took me 2 days to identify the cause.. happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
SELECT count(*) AS COUNT
FROM
  ( SELECT DISTINCT field#1,
                    field#2
   FROM some_table1 st1,
        some_table2
   WHERE st1.id = st2.id
     AND st1.updated_date BETWEEN to_date(?, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:mi:ss') AND to_date(?, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:mi:ss') )
```